# Read a local data set using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

I want to use Virtuoso SPARQL Editor, to query an rdf or nt file which is stored in my local pc (c\documents\file1.nt). How to include such path in the namespace and FROM clause SPARQL query.

Comment: What? Virtuoso is a triple store and not a "SPARQL Query Editor". Load the data into the triple store and then you can run the query against the data. Documentation is online

Comment: It is online SPARQL editor in this link: http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: You would need a local Virtuoso instance running on your PC ***or*** your local file would need to be HTTP-accessible by the remote Virtuoso instance.  Also, the Virtuoso instance would need to be configured to allow such queries (which the DBpedia instance is not).  Followup for more detailed discussion would be better on the [OpenLink Community Forum](http://community.openlinksw.com) or the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/).

Comment: One way to easily query a local RDF file in SPARQL is to use Jena command line tools : https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/index.html